# Override user default in Xcode UI test with key containing whitespaces

Tags: cocoa, xctest

In my UI test I'm trying to force some user defaults. It seems that one can override them with code such as:

```
var app = XCUIApplication()
app.launchArguments += ["-myUserDefaultKey", "value"]
app.launch()
```

But I would like to replace the value of a default where the key contains whitespaces, such as the key created automatically when setting `NSSplitView.autosaveName = "someSplitView"`, which is `NSSplitView Subview Frames someSplitView`. I tried escaping the whitespaces with `NSSplitView\\ Subview\\ Frames\\ someSplitView` and putting the key between single or double quotes, but nothing helped. Is this somehow possible?

Also, what would be the preferred way of temporarily removing a user default instead of overwriting it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an answer on the [Apple Developer Forums](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/726603). User defaults with spaces can be used as they are (I hadn't even tried it because I'm so used to having to escape whitespaces in the Terminal):

```
app.launchArguments += ["-NSSplitView Subview Frames someSplitView", "value"]
```

Removing user defaults apparently is not possible.